# Number of $7$-digit positive integers with digital sum equal to $48$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many $7$-digit positive integers are there with digit sum $48$? Leading zero is not allowed.

My approach : consider a number $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7$ where $x_1$ isn't $0$. Now, the solution of $x_1+ \dots + x_7=48$ in the set of $W$ is $C(54,6)$ where $x_1$ can be $0$ too, which we don't want and we need to get rid of the solutions starting with $0$. Number of solutions starting with $0$ of this equation : $0+x_2+x_3+ \dots +x_7=48$ is $C(53,5)$, which is the number we want to get rid of from $C(54,6)$. Thus required answer would be $C(54,6)-C(53,5)$. But the answer given is way different than my one. If any, where have I went wrong?

Comment: You may have included numbers where the largest digit is bigger than $9$

Comment: I have included numbers 0<=xi<=9, 1<=i<=7 for the first one I believe.

Comment: Did you exclude invalid cases like $x_1=48$?

Comment: Let me suggest "sum of digits" is more apt than "digital sum", since [the latter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root) is often used to signify the iterative process of summing digits to get a single digit (also called "casting out nines").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong: $C(54,6)$ assumes that digitis like '32' or '15' are allowed. This is **not** a "stars and bars" problem.

Denote with $Z(l,s)$ the number of integers of length $l$ with sum of digits equal to $s$ assuming that leading zero is allowed.

You have the following recurrence formula:

$$Z(l,s)=\sum_{d=0}^{d=9}Z(l-1,s-d)$$

...with the following exit criteria:

$$Z(1,s)=0 \quad \text{if} \quad s<0 \lor s>9$$

$$Z(1,s)=1 \quad \text{if}\quad  \ 0 \le s \le 9$$

You are actually trying to calculate $Z(7, 48)-Z(6,48)$ (this eliminates all 7-digit numbers with a leading zero):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int count(int length, int sum) {
    if(length == 1) 
        return (sum >= 0 && sum <= 9)? 1: 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) 
        cnt += count(length - 1, sum - i);
    return cnt;
}

int main() {
    cout << (count(7, 48) - count(6, 48));
}
```

...and the result is 50568.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will look into the stars and bars method again to clarify it's idea.